# Saving time in Android Bundle

Tags: android

How can I save the current time in via Bundle and then when app is back to foreground show in Toast how long it is since the app was minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking up your problem into smaller parts will make this easier for you.

First, you can get the current system time using [`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()).

You also seem to already be aware of [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [`onRestoreInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)).

Inside `onSaveInstanceState()` you can simply add the current time to your state Bundle like so:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    savedInstanceState.putLong("time", currentTime);
}
```

Getting that time in `onRestoreInstanceState()` simply consists of calling `savedInstanceState.getLong("time");`.

Then just call `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` again to get the time at restoration, do some basic math to figure out how much time elapsed, and show a Toast.

Comment: .. Then just call elapsed**Real**Time again. - Also this will cause trouble when paired with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode - elapsed time resets with reboots.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I specifically selected `elapsedRealtime()` in this case because reboots don't matter. A reboot would wipe out any saved instance state for an Activity, and thus `onRestoreInstanceState()` won't be called. Definitely a good call out for anyone looking to use this method elsewhere though.

Comment: `android:persistableMode="persistAcrossReboots"` on activities in the manifest since API21 can do exactly that. You don't find much on it: http://xmodulo.com/document-centric-apps-concurrent-tasks-android.html for example